# iOS Provisioning Profile Status keeps changing to invalid

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Has anyone run into the issue where your iOS Provisioning Profiles status change after a short amount of time or after uploading an app? Over the past few days I have noticed the status for an app I am working on is always invalid when I go to upload a new test version. I go to developer.apple.com. Re-generate the same profile. Status changes to active. I then can upload the app no problem. By the time I am ready to upload another test it is back to being set to to invalid. 
Usually within 24 hours.

I have not changed any settings on the app, devices on the devise list, or the cert(s) / profiles associated with this app. It seems to happen even if I do not upload a new version. Yesterday the Provision Profile status was invalid. I logged in, re-generated, and the status was again active. I did nothing else for the rest of the day. Today I just logged in to check and again it is set to invalid.